# Plotting big tables with Plotly

Tags: python, csv, plot, visualization, plotly

I am having trouble plotting a table with plotly using a .csv file with 2000 rows by 5 columns. It generates an html file for me, but I am having trouble opening it, and when I open it with chrome, it says the page is unresponsive and offers to kill the process.

If I plot just a sample of the data, like the first 100 rows, it works fine. However, Ideally I need the whole .csv plotted as a table in plotly. Is there a way to do this, or are there some sort of limitations?

This is the code:

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF
plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='########',api_key='########')
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

table = FF.create_table(df)
py.iplot(table, filename='linked_table')
plotly.offline.plot(table, filename='file.html') #allows to plot offline and opens .html file generated in browser
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried to look online but found nothing.

Comment: Can anyone please give me a suggestion on what to do? Thanks.